# How to show other methods that overloads the chosen?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, list

for example I have

```
extension = new List<string>();
```

If I look at the source I can see there are

```
  public List(int capacity);
```

and

```
public List(IEnumerable<T> collection);
```

Is there any way to activate a hint that will tell me what possible arguments are?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is automatically provided by "IntelliSense".

When you type left bracket in your source code above, the "hint" appears. Or put cursor after left bracket and press Ctrl+Shift+Space.